# I rolled back to my first commit through carelessness. Is there a way to get the latest commit out?

Tags: git

I'm not sure what I did because I don't really understand git and just started entering commands.  My intention was to delete the changes I had made since my last commit, but it looks like I've deleted all changes since my first commit, inside the repository.  When I run git log, only the commit from 2/23 is showing up.  Is there a command to get the latest version back out?

@Adrian pointed out git reflog:  Here's my output.  What is the command to checkout HEAD@{1}?

```
26ceb46 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 26ceb4673a42710adb16840cc2f96e2073869eb5
e9c0494 HEAD@{1}: commit: After root fiasco, about to change illustration, novel, and edition models
e6ca6e6 HEAD@{2}: commit: Before adding edition as a table
17b2d98 HEAD@{3}: commit: Added search grid view, pagination on search grid view and index view.
d582f81 HEAD@{4}: commit: Before fixing tag display page
117cf37 HEAD@{5}: commit: Commit before adding tagging_id to illustration table
a543a4b HEAD@{6}: commit: Search bar and search results page working
d372d6e HEAD@{7}: commit: Fixed formatting, added search bar
0188759 HEAD@{8}: commit: Style changes, implemented basic grid views, Removed extra models/controlle
003cc92 HEAD@{9}: commit: Swapped to mysql
8cfd94e HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to mysql-transition
8cfd94e HEAD@{11}: commit: Before Novel
2cc012b HEAD@{12}: commit: Archive Scaffold
26ceb46 HEAD@{13}: commit (initial): Archive Scaffold
```

Comment: Now type `git checkout (hash of commit which was your HEAD before you started playing)`.

Comment: You did me a solid Adrian.  I wish I could better express my gratitude via the web!

Comment: Reflog is your friend :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `git reflog`. You will be listed all history of your changes. You can safely checkout to commit before your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've identified the commit you want to restore, you can issue the command

```
git checkout e9c0494
```

Answer (score 0):

This should list all the unreachable commits still present in your reflog.

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs 2>/dev/null | grep 'unreachable commit' | awk '{print $3;}
```

Then you could run `git show SHA1` to display the commit message and the diff.

Note that unreachable git commits are kept in reflogs for a period of only 30 days.

**Example:**

```
$ git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs 2>/dev/null | grep 'unreachable commit' | awk '{print $3;}
bb308ef25fd7c3e0e5643bfec6a64c990724f25c
f0067516d9ce241a7fad1d03f4bd418172d1c7c4
f226f1200efdbe3687760e717d6670715e288439

$ git show bb308ef25fd7c3e0e5643bfec6a64c990724f25c
commit bb308ef25fd7c3e0e5643bfec6a64c990724f25c
Author: Ash <tuxdude@Suse1520>
Date:   Sat Mar 23 13:36:36 2013 -0700

    Removed Something.

diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index b9330fb..e69de29 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-SOMETHING
```

If you want to see how a work-tree looks like, you could also directly checkout that commit using `git checkout SHA1`